# PayPal payment with credit cards

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I have a problem with integration of paypal payment. I want to make it so that customers can't register to paypal, but paypal only shows the register to paypal.

I use php library. Is it possible that they add only credit card without registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Payments Standard, Express Checkout, Adaptive Payments, or anything that actually redirects the user over to PayPal then it would be done with "guest checkout", which is an option on that checkout screen.  In order to make that work you would need to make sure the PayPal Account Optional setting is enabled in your PayPal profile.

If you go with Payments Advanced you would imbed an iframe in your site that PayPal actually hosts, and it would have the PayPal option as well as credit card option built in to that.

Payments Pro would give you full freedom to process credit cards directly via API request, and then you wouldn't have to display any PayPal logos or show that PayPal was involved at all in that case.

I would still recommend leaving PayPal as an option for people, though.

[My site](http://www.angelleye.com/product/general-consult/) is actually is a good example.  Notice if you add that item to the cart you'll see the option to "Pay with a Credit Card" or "Pay with PayPal".  If you choose credit card that would move to a credit card form and would be processed through Payments Pro (PayFlow).  If you choose PayPal it would go through Express Checkout.  So you still give people both options, but it's very straight forward for non-PayPal users.

Answer (score 0):

You can send money to anyone with an email address but in order to claim the funds they would have to open a PayPal account.  What happens is that you send the money to their email address, they get an email letting them know they have received funds.  They are then instructed to follow the directions to open an account to receive the funds into their PayPal balance.  It is a very straightforward process and a new account can be set up very quickly.  Thanks for your great question and I hope you have a great day.

Comment: But I wanna know If exist any php function what show only credit cards without registration.

Comment: And I have to set any settings in my bussines account?

Comment: As per my knowledge, no need for it. When you will redirected to PayPal, there will be already option to pay with or without account.